# How to instance a class using array | Kotlin

Tags: class, kotlin, object

I need to create an instance of a class using an array of values.

- I know how much parameters the class have
- All class parameters are string

I tried:

```
class Person(val name: String, val lastName: String)
{

}

fun main()
{
   val values= listOf<String>("James", "Smith")
   val myPerson = Person(values);
}
```

Is possibly do something like that?

Comment: *I need to create an instance of a class using an array of values* - could you please explain why you need that? It looks quite brittle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom constructor that takes a list and uses it to instantiate your class:

```java
class Person(val name: String, val lastName: String) {
    constructor(values: List<String>) : this(values[0], values[1])
}
```

However, I would say you should avoid this since it is very error-prone (what if the provided `values` list is empty or have only one element?).

Comment: Mmm. Another reason to avoid this is the lack of documentation/readability. When you call a constructor, your IDE can show you (via tooltips or hints or whatever) the names of the parameter(s), and any doc comment(s) attached to them. For the primary constructor, that would be very informative; not so for the secondary one.

Comment: (In fact, if you wanted to make it even clearer, you could provide the parameter names when calling the primary constructor, e.g. `Person(name = "Fred", lastName = "Bloggs")`, and even give the parameters in any order; the secondary constructor doesn't let you do either of those.)

Comment: I agree with @gidds on this. I guess I would first advise to use `values[0]` and `values[1]` as arguments on the call site before suggesting declaring such a constructor. Not sure whether the OP needs this in several places or not.